# What does the collection returned by CrmRestKit.RetrieveMultiple look like?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

In a form in CRM2011 I am using a JavaScript function to retrieve some attributes from a custom entity unrelated to the one in the form.

I have a successful call to CrmRestKit.RetrieveMultiple but I don't know what the returned collection comprises.  Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

To be a little more specific about the requirement: the query returns a set of Field schema names; i.e. the column being queried is in a custom entity and contains schema names of Fields.  I want to match each one I retrieve against the calling form's collection of Field-based controls so that I can perform an action on matching ones.  Any assistance towards that would also be gratefully received, thanks.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to debug javascript in IE?

Comment: Daryl, having looked at the other two answers, that does look like what I should be doing.  I feel a bit stupid now...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found to know what you'll be working with is to take the output and run it through JSON.stringify() and write the contents of that out to the page.

Comment: Isn't every answer a suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'll try it when I get back to work.

Answer (score 1):

For bits like this I usually just debug with IE. That will allow you to add breakpoints and inspect the object.

Related info: [Debugging Script with the Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks James, I am not at work for a few days but I will try that.